# How to change current directory in JAVA?

Tags: java

I am writing a java program to read a file whose path is in a setting xml file. And the path is not absolute but relative to the xml file. So how should I do to change the current directory to the directory of the xml file and then use the relative file path to open the file?

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: You can't change the default working directory of the process.  You should be able to change the relative directory for the XML library but how depends on the library.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29

Comment: What prevents you to concatenate the relative path found in the xml to xml path ?

Comment: I just think that is not so elegant. So far it seems the only way to do it. @fxm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot re-assign the default working directory of your process - it is given to your program at JVM's start-up, and does not change throughout the lifetime of the program.

In order to evaluate a relative path, construct an absolute path from the path of the origin (the XML file), a file path separator, and the relative path:

```
String xmlFilePath = "c:\\temp\\xml\\my_file.xml";
String relativePath = "..\\resources\\file.ico";
String resourcePath = "c:\\temp\\xml\\..\\resources\\file.ico";
```

Java will interpret paths like that as `"c:\\temp\\resources\\file.ico"`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do this, as you may have some absolute `Path` and resolve paths from it:

```
Path basePath = ...
Path resourcePath = basePath.resolve(relativePath);
```