# Change directory only for duration of program in Java

Tags: java, directory, working-directory

Using the various Java APIs I can implement the following shell commands in Java successfully: `pwd, dir/ls, copy/cp, del/rm` without invoking the shell itself to execute these command to for me.

E.g.,

```
    case "pwd":
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        break;

    case "dir":
    case "ls":
        File myDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        String[] filesInDir = myDir.list();
        for(String fn: filesInDir)
            System.out.println(fn);
        break;
```

The only basic command that is giving me trouble is **"cd"**. Surely there must be an API function that would let me do this? However if there is I've missed it.

Note: I am not trying to execute anything external to the program, I simply want to be able to navigate the file system interactively for the duration of the program run and manipulate files in a very limited way via the API. In other words, this program emulates a very basic shell.

I've seen these question, but they haven't really helped, one states this is not possible, true?

[How to change current directory in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825055/how-to-change-current-directory-in-java)

[Changing the current working directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190/changing-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

[Changing the current directory in Java to implement "cd" command in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631456/changing-the-current-directory-in-java-to-implement-cd-command-in-linux)

Using Windows 7 with JDK 7.

Comment: Not possible. See bug at http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4045688

Comment: @Jayan  Wow (and interesting) .. it seems like such a basic file system operation for it not to be implemented - thanks for the link. I wonder if there's another workaround for this.

Comment: The question you quoted 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840190' has all reasonable options listed. (ProcessBuilder, JNI/JNA...)

Comment: Ok, thanks all .. I guess I'll delete this then.

Comment: unable to delete ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such api function but you can emulate it: store current directory in variable. During initialization assign this variable to System.getProperty("user.dir"). In all your methods use this variable. "cd" command should change this variable.